# Deploy individual microservice using Jenkins pipeline in a multimodule spring boot microservices project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins-pipeline, microservices, multi-module

I have a microservices project i.e structured as multimodule maven project with spring boot ,e.g

- microservice-module-1
- microservice-module-2
- parent-module with parent pom

All microservices are packed under one scm repository. I want to setup a CI CD pipeline using Jenkins pipelines for my microservices . If some changes are made in **microservice-module-1** in repository then I want to deploy that particular microservice or module, webhook will notify jenkins for any change under parent repo but after packaging I want to deploy only microservice which was affected. There are reasons for this : -

- deploying all microservices again will take huge build and deployment time .
- Also many test stages will add up more time .

So in my continuous delivery pipeline in Jenkins when a webhook trigger I want to deploy only changed services. Maven incremental plugin may serve the purpose but I want to know in context of microservices packaged as maven multimodule projectd.  Please tell me how to achieve this or If this approach should not be followed then please suggest best approach in this context.

Comment: Why don't you use separate repositories for every microservice? That would allow you to rely purely on commits to determine whether or not something changed in one of those "modules". It would also allow you to separate your pipelines so that you only need to deploy one artifact for every run.

Comment: @g00glen00b we are thinking to use separate repositories for each microservices . But I saw many examples online i.e. microservices packaged like maven multi module project so how they are doing continuous deployment . Also in future when my project will grow big then managing all repositories and their pipeline jobs will be difficult .

Comment: @g00glen00b also I think in big projects maintaining multiple repositories for each small or big microservice is not easy and also adds up to total cost unnecessarily .

Comment: Well, it's offtopic/opinionated, but microservices usually end up being developed and managed by different people, so having one big repo often adds to the complexity (merging for no reason), rather than simplifying it. The cost is also relative, since you don't know yet how much it costs to deploy a multi-module Maven project the way you want it.

Comment: @g00glen00b thanks for valuable advice and I agree with your points . But just in case If I proceed with multi module structure . Can you advice some way how to achieve continuous delivery so that I don't end up deploying all microservices which were not affected in repository. I need to identify particular artifact which was changed and deploy only that one only . Every sub module is a spring boot project .